# how to fix the date error using Date.now()

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript

I am using Date.now() to get the current date and time, but I didn't know the problem I am having. The scenario is this that I use console to check whether date.now() generating correct time or not? Unfortunately I got the correct date in Unix code value  convert and check that was correct time and date but when I put that in mongoo schema it used few hours back and store date with few hours back time. But when I get that object with date it returns me the few hours back date and time but when I bind that with Angular front it shows me the correct time the time I put on mongoo the problem is I am not able to filter data by date bcs that object contain few hours back time.

Here is the typescript object that I am pushing on the mongoo

```
bill = {
    orderArray: [],
    //investment total
    totalActual:0,
    //sale total
    totalSale: 0,
    //investment - sale 
    totalSave: 0,
    quantity: 0,
    date: Date.now()
}
```

and here is the mongo schema:

```
var cartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    orderArray: Array,
    date: { type: Date,  default: Date.now },
    totalActual: Number,
    totalSale: Number,
    totalSave: Number,
})
```

Comment: Your mongo schema is having a different timezone. Do make sure that angular and mongo db both have the same timezone. Also, it is always better to store date value as UTC and while reading the date on client-side, convert it to user specific timezone.

Comment: i am working on this from two weeks and from last two weeks i was working fine but last night suddenly iface this problem before that it was pretty good with date

Comment: Yes, it usually happens when timezone of the system gets changed and when timezone is not explicitly mentioned in the source code.

Comment: thanks for helping . could you please send me the guide link of any documentation or whatever you can do . actually i am the beginner i dn know much . an thanks by the way to be there .

Comment: why i got the exact date and exact time when i am printing on client side but i got the console responce with the wrong date when i bind on the client side how it gets to the right date time. but i am getting that wrong date

Comment: Refer this for DatePipe feature and timezone related parameters: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#parameters

Comment: Are your application is running in local server or remote server? Sometimes the remote server has different time-zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please check to whether your DB server and application running in the same timezone
2. Or convert your local time to UTC format from application side and pass it MongoDB

Comment: my db serve and application is running on same system

Comment: I have tried every possible way but i still got the 5 hours back of time